# Storing the values of dynamically added checkboxes from userforms

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjKlJ.jpg)I have a user in which I am creating 7 checkboxes programmatically, and removing the same using 2 command buttons. Now, I am facing issues when I am trying to read/ store the value of a checkbox when clicked.

I have used the Class Module -

```
Public WithEvents cBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cbox_click()
    msgbox cBox.Name & " clicked. Value is now " & IIf(cBox.Value, "Checked", "Unchecked")
End Sub
```

And in UserForm -

```
Dim chkBoxEvent As clsBoxEvent
Dim chkBoxColl As Collection

Private Sub btnAddClass_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, newCtrl As Control, offsetTop As Integer
    Set chkBoxColl = New Collection

    offsetTop = 36

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) <> "CommandButton" Then
            If ctrl.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop Then
                If TypeName(ctrl) = "ComboBox" Then
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
                ElseIf TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" Then
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
                End If
                nchk = 7
                If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
                For i = 1 To nchk
                    Set newCtrl = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1")

                    With newCtrl
                        .Height = ctrl.Height
                        .Width = ctrl.Width
                        .Top = ctrl.Top + offsetTop
                        .Left = ctrl.Left
                        .Tag = nchk * 10
                    End With
                    Set chkBoxEvent = New clsBoxEvent
                    Set chkBoxEvent.cBox = Me.Controls(newCtrl.Name)
                    chkBoxColl.Add chkBoxEvent
                Next
                End If
                If TypeName(newCtrl) <> "CheckBox" Then
                    With newCtrl
                        .Height = ctrl.Height
                        .Width = ctrl.Width
                        .Top = ctrl.Top + offsetTop
                        .Left = ctrl.Left
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    btnAddClass.Top = btnAddClass.Top + offsetTop
    btnRemoveClass.Top = btnRemoveClass.Top + offsetTop
    Me.Height = Me.Height + offsetTop
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveClass_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, offsetTop As Integer
    offsetTop = 36

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) <> "CommandButton" Then
            If ctrl.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop Then
                Me.Controls.Remove (ctrl.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl
    btnAddClass.Top = btnAddClass.Top - offsetTop
    btnRemoveClass.Top = btnRemoveClass.Top - offsetTop
    Me.Height = Me.Height - offsetTop
End Sub
```

Each time new set of checkboxes are added, the `msgbox` displays as "CheckBox22, 99, 110, 789" etc random numbers.

Comment: You don't set the names for the added checkbox, so why do the names matter here?  BTW `Me.Controls(newCtrl.Name)` is the same as just `newCtrl`

Comment: I want to record which checkboxes was clicked by the user, and based on that I need to perform another set of operations.

Comment: You can name your checkboxes using some meaningful scheme, so you know which one is which, or add another field to your custom class so you can track whatever information is relevant.

Comment: I am very new to VBA, dont have advance experience. Could you guide me to create custom class to track the event?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want to happen when a checkbox is clicked.  What does each checkbox represent, and when do they need to be read to find their values?  Does some action need to occur on each click?  There are no details in your question, and we can't write code without knowing what it needs to handle.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that! Each checkboxes represent insurance plans, so when user chooses (tick) a particular plan(s) or checkbox, it has to store in the excel sheet. Because, based on the plans chosen other formulas will be built.

Comment: Does it need to store the value as soon as a box is checked, or is there a "submit" button which triggers the calculations?  Where is the logic which determines which checkbox is linked to which cell on the worksheet?

Comment: No submit button, so it will be when the checkboxes are clicked. The values can go into a sheet in any range, I'll work around it.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot of how the userform is. Bascially, when the user comes to this for, they will choose which category their client falls into in "Class Name", and how many lives in 2nd textbox. And the first checkbox is always mandatory for any new classname. Out of LTD,STD, Dental and HSA any 1 has to be chosen, rest are optional.

Comment: Looks like you also need to manage multiple rows of controls - if the user clicks "add class" more than once?

Comment: Seems like LTD,STD, Dental and HSA ashould be presented as option buttons, and the first checkbox should fixed "on" and disabled?

Comment: Thats right, add class can be N times, that's why I have auto adjust the form height and shift the buttons along the addition. Yes, first checkbox for mandatory Life should be on when new class is added and disabled.

Comment: Is it a doable requirement in VBA?

Comment: Most things are doable - the main challenge is finalizing your requirements.  For example what does the "Remove class" button do if you have (eg) three rows of controls?  You really need a "remove" button on each row.

Comment: Remove button has to remove a particular class name. Out of 5 class names, a inputbox to enter the class name which has to be deleted.

Comment: right now the code deletes only the last row of controls.

Comment: I have emailed you the workbook. Please take a look into this.